# UWP multiple view: Close all secondary view when main view is closed

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

As in the title, I follow [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) but there's no mention of how to achieve what I want: I have a custom control that is **either** embedded in the app's main view **or** put in a secondary view for screen space. The behavior I need is:

1. When the app main view is closed (i.e. via the system X button on the top right corner, not something in my xaml), I want to close all secondary views that the app created and terminate the app.
2. When the secondary view is closed (i.e. via the system X button on the top right corner, not my own xaml button), I want to notify the main view to re-create it inside it.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario? It seems that there's no way to capture the "X button pressed" event in UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this scenario? It seems that there's no way to capture the "X button pressed" event in UWP.

There's a [CloseRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested) event of [SystemNavigationManagerPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview) class. This event occurs when the user invokes the system button for close (the 'x' button in the corner of the app's title bar).

Please note that if you want to use this event, you need to add a [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) `confirmAppClose` in 'Package.appxmanifest' file.